# Complete NaN values in a dataframe based on the values completed in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join

So, what i am trying to do, is complete the NaN values of a Dataframe with the correct values that are to be found in a second dataframe. It would be something like this

```
df={"Name":["Lennon","Mercury","Jagger"],"Band":["The Beatles", "Queen", NaN]}
df2={"Name":["Jagger"],"Band":["The Rolling Stones"]}
```

So, I have this command to know which rows have at least one NaN:

```
inds = list(pd.isnull(dfinal).any(1).nonzero()[0].astype(int))
```

I thought this would be useful to use a for like function (didn't succeed there)

And then I tried this:

```
result=df.join(dfinal, on=["Name"])
```

But it gives me the following error

> ValueError: You are trying to merge on object and int64 columns. If
> you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat

I checked, and both Series "Name" are string values. So i am unable to solve this.

Keep in mind there are more columns, and the likely result it would be that if a row has one NaN, it will have like 7 NaN.

It is there a way to solve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## `Map` and `Fillna(`)

we can target missing values in your target df with missing values from the second dataframe based on the `Name` column.

```
df["Band"] = df["Band"].fillna(df["Name"].map(df2.set_index("Name")["Band"]))

print(df)


      Name                Band
0   Lennon         The Beatles
1  Mercury               Queen
2   Jagger  The Rolling Stones
```

Comment: Thanks! This is really helpful. Is it there a way to make these run thru several columns at the same time? I tried inserting more than one column name, but does not seem to work.

Comment: @BrunoSapia there is indeed, but I need a sample that matches your problem. Does the Name clolumn stay constant? if you can add 5 rows with 3-4 columns that would be ideal.

Comment: So, yes, the Name Column would stay constant. And the rest of the columns can be whatever Address, Band, DoB.
It may happened that when matching both dataframes for one or more rows it would still be NaN. After that I would show an error message showing the names that have missing data and have to be manually added in an excel file before running the script again.

The column names of dataframe2 will always be found in dataframe1. I have manipulation over that, so the idea is for them not to change.

Comment: I did this 

for i in columns:
    df1[i]=df1[i].fillna(df1["Alias"].map(df2.set_index("Alias")[i]))

Comment: well that works :) another method would be to re-shape your dataframe but i dont want to guess as you've not provided a sample.